# What does 并没有 mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

I am confused about the usage of character 并 with 没有来, as in this sentence:

> 他并没有来北京

Does it mean:

1. She never (and will not) come to Beijing.
2. She hasn't come to Beijing, yet. (but she will come soon)

Comment: 并 conj.and,furthermore, adv. also, 他并没有来北京 he also did not go (has not come) to Beijing

Comment: 并 often appears not directly translated in English, see examples for 并 in iciba one such: She probably sensed that I wasn'ttelling her the whole story.
她可能意识到了我并没有对她全盘托出。

Comment: In this context, 并没有来 has the implication that he had the plan to come to Beijing or I thought he would come to Beijing, but he did not.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> [並 / 并](http://www.cantonese.sheik.co.uk/dictionary/characters/844/)
>
> [3] [adv] (used before a negative for emphasis) **actually**; **definitely**; **really**

Examples:

只此一家, 無分店. - Only one store location, no branch.

只此一家, [**並**]無分店. - Only one store location, [**definitely**] no branch.

~

人們誠心向佛, 但彿祖未能救他們於水火 - People sincerely believed in Buddha, but the Buddha couldn't save them from suffering.

人們誠心向佛, 但彿祖[**並**]未能救他們於水火 - People sincerely believed in Buddha, but the Buddha [**really**] couldn't  save them from suffering.

~

美軍的強大，不是加軍能比疑的 - The strength of the US military, is not the one Canadian military can compare

美軍的強大，[**並**]不是加軍能比疑的 - The strength of the US military, is [**definitely**] not the one Canadian military can compare

~

他没有来北京 - He did not come to Beijing.

他[**并**]没有来北京 - He [**actually**] did not come to Beijing.

> 并 is used before a negative for **emphasis**

Anna Zhou suggested:

> *and it is implied that people thought/estimated he would come to Beijing.*

It could also mean 'he didn't make it after all' or 'he changed his mind'

The point is, '并' emphasizes the negative aspect in the sentence regardless of reason